# Displaying blob images in php

Tags: php, image, blob

I am trying to display blog images using image source. The following is how I insert images into MYSQL database using php and stored into a directory called 'picture'. The insert was successful

```
<form method="post" action="post.php" enctype ="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif"  name="image" id="image"/> 
   <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-info"/>
 </form>

  if (isset($_POST['post']) && isset($_FILES['image'])) {
   $target_dir = "picture/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $image=basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"],".jpg");
    $stmt = "INSERT INTO post (image) values (:image)";
    $p = $MySQLi_CON -> prepare($stmt);
    $results = $p -> execute(array(
                    ":image" => $image
                ));
    }
```

However, the issue here is when I try to display it in a `img-src`, the image link is broken and it doesn't display anything. I have tried to `echo $key['image']`, it seems to output the correct image name but not the image itself

```
<tbody>
          <?php 
                     $query = "SELECT * FROM test";
                     $data = $MySQLi_CON->query($query);
                     foreach ($data as $key ) {
                   ?>
          <tr class="active">
            <td><div class = "col-sm-6 col-md-2">
      <a  class = "thumbnail">
        <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $key['image'] ).'" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail"/>';?>        
      </a>
   </div></td>  
            <td><?php echo $key['image'];?></td> //it gives value such as picture.jpg, image.png
          </tr>
                <?php
                  }
                  ?>          
   </tbody>
```

Comment: A suggestion. Don't store images in mysql. Instead store image source of images in the database thats more useful.

Comment: Things like Amazon S3 storage will help you store images if you want to take @ResheilAgarwal advice

Comment: Where do you think you are storing BLOBs into the database here? All you insert is the content of the variable `$image`, and the value of that is just `basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"],".jpg")` - that ain't no BLOB ...

Answer (score 0):

You do not store the full path in $image variable, try something like:

$image = $target_dir . basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"].".jpg");

Also consider the manual on "basename":
http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

You may also want to consider having paths in a DB as a bad thing, because if the path in your file structure changes, that will cause all kinds of fun things to happen.

You can avoid havoc by saving just the filename as you are doing now, just correct the extension problem on the basename statement and then prepend the path to the filename on the display code.

If you don't mind a large database, you can store the image source in the database. I generally don't recommend source in database fields, but on smaller tables with few records you should be OK.

Hope that helps.